# In Germany with expired Schengen visa. Cannot return home due to coronavirus

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas, covid-19, visa-expiration

My friend had a 15-days visa from France. His flight to Iran got canceled because of the coronavirus. After that, he came to Germany (Munich) because he had relatives here and went to the immigration office (KVR) to extend his visa. They told him that he can extend his visa but he should provide insurance. After providing insurance the immigration office got closed. He has sent several emails but he hasn't got any response yet. His visa is expired now and we are so worried about this issue. Is it possible for him to go back to Iran with an expired visa in this situation? The border police say that it's not possible and going back is an emergency now for him.

Do you have any suggestions for this situation?

Comment: Given that flights are cancelled... how is your friend planning to go back?

Comment: I do not think anyone is going to stop him from leaving, that is **if he can**

Comment: @JonathanReez His flight got canceled at that time and all the other available flights were so expensive for the next day. So he went to KVR to extend his visa and find an appropriate flight, but after that, Munich went on quarantine and everything got complicated.

Comment: @user56513 He doesn't have a valid visa, so we are so worried that he might never be able to get a visa again or the police punish him because of staying without a visa. But it's not on purpose and he already has sent his documents to the immigration office already but they don't respond.

Comment: Do not sent emails, call them instead. In my experience getting email answer from offices is already as slow as paper mail in normal times. Now that they are closed, it is likely there is only a single person present for emergency cases

Comment: @Manziel He tried to call them, but the person who answers said that he doesn't have access to the process and only his colleagues are responsible for visa extension and they are not there. Is there any other number that someone responsible can be reachable by it?

Comment: the German administration has almost a fetish for old fashion letters; emails will be ignored, phone calls forgotten. Germany takes paper mail very seriously and the post system is extremely efficient. It is the best way to document the case. I don't know in the EU, but I dealt with employees' visas in the US and circumstances out of control were usually well understood and never led to problems. If anything Germans are quite practical, so I wouldn't worry about it as long as he has updated the proper authorities about his situation.

Comment: It might be wise to keep some evidence (like copies of eMails / for telephone calls write down day, time and the name of the person you spoke to) so that you can show you contacted the authorities on your own initiative.

Answer (score 17):

The visa status should not prevent him from leaving Germany. Under normal circumstances overstays may be punished, but for people who leave on their own after a few days that would at most be a fine. That makes the response by the border police puzzling. Are you sure nothing was lost in translation?

The city of Munich [writes](https://www.muenchen.de/rathaus/Stadtverwaltung/Kreisverwaltungsreferat/Auslaenderwesen/Aktuelle-Meldung.html#mein-aufenthaltstitel-visum-luft-ab-was-nun_4):

- Contact the KVR before the visa expires. He has done that.
- He will receive a certification which is valid until the KVR reopens. That hasn't happened yet.
- If there is no reply yet, he should send a mail with scans of

  - Passport and visa
  - A confirmation of the hotel or host where he is staying.
  - A proof that departure is impossible. (They don't say what that is.)
  - If available, proof of health insurance.

So it seems that he did everything required and the city administration can't keep up.

He should take care to get everything documented properly so that there are no problems with the *next* Schengen visa application.

---

While I understand that returning home might be a personal emergency for him, I would think that Munich is reasonably safe at this time. Germany has more confirmed infections than Iran, but fatalities are fewer.

Comment: We called the immigration office today, they told us that the police know the situation and he shouldn't be worried, but when we sent an email to police, they told us that it's not legal to stay in Germany without a visa and it's not recommended to leave without a visa. I don't know if it's a normal situation to leave a country when your visa has been expired. Besides safety, we are worried that staying in Germany without a valid visa might cause him a serious problem, on the other hand, the immigration office doesn't reply to any email to make it clear whether they will extend the visa or not

Comment: @user137927, first step, take a deep breath. Yesterday and the day before were the weekend. Personnel might have been reassigned to the health administration.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm just worried that something weird happens due to this situation.

Comment: @user137927 "it's not legal to stay in Germany without a visa and it's not recommended to leave without a visa": they say that because they are in charge of enforcing the law, so they have to say it. But that doesn't mean that they're going to pursue vigorous enforcement against him. He is making concerted efforts to regularize his stay because he cannot leave the country. As long as he documents those efforts (as recommended here) and leaves as soon as he can, there shouldn't be too much trouble. Records of his efforts will help not only with the next application but also with his departure.

Comment: Note that Portugal [Has given migrants and asylum seekers full citizenship rights so they can make use of healthcare.](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/03/30/europe/portugal-migrants-citizenship-rights-coronavirus-intl) It's possible that Germany might do the same.

Comment: @Nzall, I consider that extremely unlikely, especially since healthcare is organized differently.

Comment: @Nzall Thanks, but I don't have any hope.

Answer (score 8):

Hi everyone and thanks a lot for all your help

The problem got solved. My friend sent an email at 7:35 (the opening time was 7:30) and attached all the needed documents. He also mentioned that he contacted the border police and they have said that he can't leave without a visa. They sent him a certificate by email that shows he is allowed to stay because of the situation.

Comment: Nice.  Thank you for coming back to tell us about the outcome.  It is good to hear that government authorities can act reasonably.

Comment: @phoog It's a pleasure that everyone tried to help us in this situation. And yes, I'm so happy that they act reasonably.